# neutral language in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, localization

I installed non-English version of Visual Studio, and now when I'm trying to localize my Windows Phone XNA game I face that neutral language is the Visual Studio language, though I explicitly set it to "en". How's that possible and what should I do?
I don't use any .resx files, so maybe this is the reason? But all languages that I support are determined well, the problem is when I set unsupported locale it somehow chooses wrong neutral language.

Comment: How are you setting the neutral language to "en"?

Comment: in AssemblyInfo.cs: [assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute("en")]

Comment: Did you test the CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture of the threads?

Comment: I just changed locales in the emulator. What I know for sure is that application determines current language and culture right.

Comment: Just tested this: Debug.WriteLine("isNeutral? " + CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IsNeutralCulture); and it returned false though I changed locale to an unsupported one. How is that possible?

Comment: Could you try and add an empty resx for the neutral language to the project?

Comment: I've already tried to add AppResources.resx to the project, but no success - isNeutral is false though locale is Swedish which I don't support.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Threads culture:

```
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
```

Add en-US to supported Culture list in the csproj file (open with Notepad)

```
<SupportedCultures>en-US;</SupportedCultures>
```

Make sure every string (UIElement) has the correct culture

```
xml:lang="en-US"
```

Comment: Mm, the problem is I want English to be the current culture if and only locale is "en" or neutral. Here it seems that I should force culture to be en-US, or I understood it wrong?